# numpy won't work in IDLE

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I'm running python 2.7.3 on window 8. I'm writing some code that requires me to use the `numpy.add()` function. I downloaded numpy 1.6.0 for win32 py 2.7 from sourceforge. I have no idea how to "build" it up, and don't want to.

Anyway, when I run my code I get "NameError: global name 'numpy' is not defined." (code begins with from numpy import *)

This happens in PyScripter and Python IDLE, but not in Python command line. In command line I can just write:

```
import numpy
numpy.add(array1, array2)
```

no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `import numpy` not `from numpy import *`

You cannot call `numpy.add` if you have not imported `numpy`.

If you used `from numpy import *` you would use `add(array1, array2)` but the best way is to use:

```
import numpy as np

np.add()
```

`from numpy import *` imports all the methods into your current namespace which is not a good idea as there are builtin and numpy methods with the same names and you can end up getting different outputs to what you might expect.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.__version__
Out[2]: '1.9.0'

In [3]: np.add(1,2)
Out[3]: 3
```

Comment: thank you. after trying import numpy as np, np.add(array1, array2) i'm getting "Not Implemented".

is this because i've failed to import properly, or because i'm using the function incorrectly?

Comment: i think its because my arrays are arrays of strings.

Comment: @CSB, yes that is the problem, what are you trying to do exactly

Comment: I was trying to read in txt files representing cell values for two rasters, and do some basic raster calculations. I was able to convert the strings via mapping and everything worked. Thanks all for the help.